# Why Mathematica doesn't compute the permutation products in my NestList[]?

Tags: iteration

I wrote the following:

```
K = DihedralGroup[5];
K = GroupGenerators[K];
y = K[[1]];
x = K[[1]];
l = NestList[PermutationProduct[x, y], x, 4]
```

But Mathematica gives me the unevaluated products as:

[image]

When it should be a sequence:

```
Cycles[{{2, 5}, {3, 4}}]
Cycles[{}]
...
```

Why is Mathematica not computing this?

Comment: Presumably you meant to use either `NestList[PermutationProduct[#, y] &, x, 4]` or `NestList[PermutationProduct[x, #] &, x, 4]` Since `x == y`, they are equivalent.

Comment: @BobHanlon What is the difference of interpretation using `x` and `#`? Everytime I looked at `#` it seemed like a variable for me.

Comment: Look at the result of `Clear[f, x, y]; NestList[f[x, y], x, 4]` The function in `NestList` must be able to accept a new argument for each step. The `Slot` indicates where the new argument goes in the function. Without a `Slot`, the function is assumed to be a single argument function with an implied argument.